# error: Error -3 while decompressing data: incorrect header check (Error occuring which decompressing base64 encoded string)

Tags: python, encoding, base64, compression

The below is successfully working code in example 1:

Example 1:

```
import zlib

import base64

data = "eJyl0b1uwyAQAOBXQcy1hLHjn65RorZppQ6VKnU74GKj2hABHqLI716ztK6aenA24Lj7TncXiibocH5U9J5QKZgSUPOEbzKRpCmKBJRME8ZzDjLljDFO7wg9ofPW+CnlQhWUWSWLfDEnfpRwCqDNdD5C53EqI7SIalbEmgZ6jLcXbJUme90M6CzEiA/gAropGNyA4/QSzZqhXG/mbG4+I5AP3ffoejD/k5WAYj2ZbubkrtPgyd6hke1fMc7Yeh20jYXoln63gGJ5O8uTLuctbHU3NWHIwV5r4WfOHG8Q67n4BGeFhjwghAWxOpZwg1jNxQN03dCTV3Cf6BdIwGo9+Wuxby1a8q6bRptr4Dh+AT9i+9U="

compressed_data = base64.b64decode(data.encode())

output = zlib.decompress(compressed_data).decode()

print(output)
```

Output:

```
{"entityId": "cb0dba92-253b-11eb-adc1-0242ac120002", "persons": {"da738c64-253b-11eb-adc1-0242ac120002": {"captain": false, "bib": "36", "name": "Mehdi Figueroa", "starter": true}, "da7390ec-253b-11eb-adc1-0242ac120002": {"captain": false, "bib": "40", "name": "Lea Zimmerman", "starter": true}, "da738ba6-253b-11eb-adc1-0242ac120002": {"captain": false, "bib": "15", "name": "Elias French", "starter": true, "position": "C"}, "da738eb2-253b-11eb-adc1-0242ac120002": {"captain": false, "bib": "37", "name": "Cillian Koch", "starter": true}, "da73902e-253b-11eb-adc1-0242ac120002": {"captain": false, "bib": "39", "name": "Jayden Heath", "starter": true}, "da738f7a-253b-11eb-adc1-0242ac120002": {"captain": false, "bib": "38", "name": "Kallum Parkes", "starter": true}, "da738ae8-253b-11eb-adc1-0242ac120002": {"captain": false, "bib": "5", "name": "Theo Wiggins", "starter": true}}}
```

The following example 2 has the same code as in example 1 but generating error: How decompression can be made successful for example 2;

Example 2:

```
import zlib

import base64

data = "Lki49VBk7tfhyXk3WyzwMBqP1u1UCxKWLJZ/yBFdgWafU8Glyu97OhkFQje2Ds+KllTVTgl5oPXc9U79JHBYz9XN344ZNTpv9CMg9BX5y4VeuPDzW7985b4Aa2TUHfGSKBYsSezbbctkSAaRZVdhJ2sjqdZH3pylcJwzAHr+Sn+Wtnib/sJDLqdLGUK3LSbPSK8Q0KQfDP5lNfavdvg8kepBPbN+Wr/oB3mtuhRjcFXe4y9BRWQTi4qGYDQ8MMlIeanrx7IaHfOvSGyBKa0TVbkixzmX2i93l6qqvKaTwoREGfdZA2jZdzzIVZWlXYU/qPkrLy873BJ0ZhXg9TE6XQ==;MZfPM47CRpWLrPw0TRDnvla4aDkJsmV5TALa0slA1TDaZj2SLOQ4dlQpy754tkFkkqLqXjNXT/u2P9vEYE2rW98vErmaevsxVhNEbcqP3UQ2bJJEzI/0oSx4KSeqe+mL+vqRbFW+Maw1vZKb1KLUzsxXq50HgxAqFbc/E/oN46DpgGceIpv0H04a0seVyKd51fZImahHi4Y7XAvgp9Jex/wAryh3sC91dMY94uwGTSlrDLbggNmTZXOKcK+GB8e7coNt5jAPbaj69XHGGSEreek8RDFZJXCqWWXsrgF248/1aVkPJoKm7yaFeZn8/A6MT5YZvH3Jc9SEnkUKEBCFAg==;0SbhqVJFrTaGsFUqPVdyag==;p+yK2V8sgj4tK0OYCHS/TMU9N6mIhrolBq5oIMjtOsjL2NTne3/6roEb9tgrrwB/34ye8yTHMx5LgrooV5AMsGhh1+cQt4qRen4kLGRzLzYin2jYyeAFQqkJKFS77PtVeGrHvGC/o/bQ6cWl6k395eXDBqlI2+DV6WG052QRtQTXYTcfsneu1fYWbIRvlBF19WmGHRkrVJAaPcEpBlh00g=="

compressed_data = base64.b64decode(data.encode())

output = zlib.decompress(compressed_data).decode()

print(output)
```

Following error occured:

> error: Error -3 while decompressing data: incorrect header check

Problem to be solved:
How example two can give successful decompression?

Comment: Please [format](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-formatting) code properly. Do *not* bold and increase the font of a large block of text, when it doesn't add anything else to the question.

Comment: The error means that the `data` in the second example is not compressed.

Comment: Yes data is not compressed. Decoding and decompression is done in the following code statements:

Comment: compressed_data = base64.b64decode(data.encode())

output = zlib.decompress(compressed_data).decode()

Answer (score 0):

Your second example, after Base64 decoding, is not a zlib stream, and does not contain deflate-compressed data.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Can you please guide me about this stream, how it will be decoded? And if it is not zlib stream, what else type it has and how it can be handled?

Comment: I have no idea what it is. You need to ask whoever you got the data from.